# Meteor - What is the simplest way to allow a user to configure a Meteor package?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm writing a Meteor/Meteorite package, and it's working, but many values are hardcoded that should be configurable.

I'd like users to be able to set values inside the package by putting

```
Package.config({
  setting1: value1, 
  setting2: value2, 
  ...
})
```

somewhere in the app code. I'd then read those values in the package with something like `PackageConfig.setting1`, `PackageConfig.setting2`, etc.

What's a good, simple way to do this? The packages I've looked at for examples seem a bit complex, and I wonder if that's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple google maps package of mine which provides a similar design pattern you're asking for :

client/lib/google-maps.js :

```
GoogleMaps={
  // public methods
  config:function(options){
    _.extend(this,options);
  },
  ready:function(){
    this._loadingDependency.depend();
    return this._ready;
  },
  // private methods
  _loaded:function(){
    this._ready=true;
    this._loadingDependency.changed();
  },
  // public members
  apiKey:"",
  // private members
  _ready:false,
  _loadingDependency:new Deps.Dependency()
};

_googleMapsLoaded=function(){
  GoogleMaps._loaded();
};

Meteor.startup(function(){
  if(!GoogleMaps.apiKey){
    throw new Meteor.Error(-1,"API key not set, use GoogleMaps.config({apiKey:YOUR_API_KEY});");
  }
  $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+GoogleMaps.apiKey+"&callback=_googleMapsLoaded");
});
```

package.js (WARNING, Meteor < 0.9 packages API, expect breaking changes in a near future)

```
Package.describe({
  summary:"Google Maps packaged for Meteor."
});

Package.on_use(function(api){
  api.use(["jquery","deps"],"client");
  //
  api.add_files([
    "client/lib/google-maps.js"
  ],"client");
  //
  api.export(["GoogleMaps","_googleMapsLoaded"],"client");
});
```

So basically it's a simple package that allows the user to specify its own google API key client side via this call : GoogleMaps.config(...);

When the maps API is fully loaded we get a notification via a reactive ready method.

I'm using a traditional OOP programming style to differentiate between what the package exposes and what is private to the implementation.
The package only exports a top level public object (GoogleMaps) which is configurable via a public interface.
You can then reference GoogleMaps.apiKey in the package implementation just as you requested.